# app on emulator running perfect but when running on real device the location marker is not visible and when running code it shows unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, geolocation, android-emulator, google-maps-markers, assets

As the problem is that everything works fine in emulator....even assets are loading successfully in emulator still the stack shows unable to load assets and moreover after successfully testing app on emulator when i run my app on my real device the location marker was not visible which was visible in the emulator

```
    //This is my code 

import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'components/map_pin_pill.dart';
import 'Model/pin_pill_info.dart';

const double CAMERA_ZOOM = 16;
const double CAMERA_TILT = 80;
const double CAMERA_BEARING = 30;
const LatLng SOURCE_LOCATION = LatLng(28.357932, 77.167889);
const LatLng DEST_LOCATION = LatLng(28.354017, 77.1605916);

void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MapPage()));

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapPageState();
}

class MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>();
// for my drawn routes on the map
  Set<Polyline> _polylines = Set<Polyline>();
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints= PolylinePoints();
  String googleAPIKey = '';
// for my custom marker pins
  BitmapDescriptor sourceIcon;
  BitmapDescriptor destinationIcon;
// the user's initial location and current location
// as it moves
  LocationData currentLocation;
// a reference to the destination location
  LocationData destinationLocation;
// wrapper around the location API
  Location location;
  double pinPillPosition = -100;
  PinInformation currentlySelectedPin = PinInformation(
      pinPath: '',
      avatarPath: '',
      location: LatLng(0, 0),
      locationName: '',
      labelColor: Colors.grey);
  PinInformation sourcePinInfo;
  PinInformation destinationPinInfo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // create an instance of Location
    location = new Location();
    polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    // subscribe to changes in the user's location
    // by "listening" to the location's onLocationChanged event
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData cLoc) {
      // cLoc contains the lat and long of the
      // current user's position in real time,
      // so we're holding on to it
      currentLocation = cLoc;
      updatePinOnMap();
    });
    // set custom marker pins
    setSourceAndDestinationIcons();
    // set the initial location
    setInitialLocation();
  }

  void setSourceAndDestinationIcons() async {
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.0), 'assets/driving_pin.png')
        .then((onValue) {
      sourceIcon = onValue;
    });

    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.0),
        'assets/destination_map_marker.png')
        .then((onValue) {
      destinationIcon = onValue;
    });
  }

  void setInitialLocation() async {
    // set the initial location by pulling the user's
    // current location from the location's getLocation()
    currentLocation = await location.getLocation();

    // hard-coded destination for this example
    destinationLocation = LocationData.fromMap({
      "latitude": DEST_LOCATION.latitude,
      "longitude": DEST_LOCATION.longitude
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
        zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
        tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
        bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
        target: SOURCE_LOCATION);
    if (currentLocation != null) {
      initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
          zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
          tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
          bearing: CAMERA_BEARING);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              compassEnabled: true,
              tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
              markers: _markers,
              polylines: _polylines,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
              onTap: (LatLng loc) {
                pinPillPosition = -100;
              },
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {//dikkat
               // controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
                _controller.complete(controller);
                // my map has completed being created;
                // i'm ready to show the pins on the map
                showPinsOnMap();
              }),
          MapPinPillComponent(
              pinPillPosition: pinPillPosition,
              currentlySelectedPin: currentlySelectedPin),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 90,
              right: 10,
              child:
              FlatButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.pin_drop, color: Colors.white),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: updatePinOnMap
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void showPinsOnMap() {
    // get a LatLng for the source location
    // from the LocationData currentLocation object
    var pinPosition =
    LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    // get a LatLng out of the LocationData object
    var destPosition =
    LatLng(destinationLocation.latitude, destinationLocation.longitude);

    sourcePinInfo = PinInformation(
        locationName: "Start Location",
        location: SOURCE_LOCATION,
        pinPath: "assets/driving_pin.png",
        avatarPath: "assets/friend1.jpg",
        labelColor: Colors.blueAccent);

    destinationPinInfo = PinInformation(
        locationName: "End Location",
        location: DEST_LOCATION,
        pinPath: "assets/destination_map_marker.png",
        avatarPath: "assets/friend2.jpg",
        labelColor: Colors.purple);

    // add the initial source location pin
    _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('sourcePin'),
        position: pinPosition,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            currentlySelectedPin = sourcePinInfo;
            pinPillPosition = 0;
          });
        },
        icon: sourceIcon));
    // destination pin
    _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('destPin'),
        position: destPosition,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            currentlySelectedPin = destinationPinInfo;
            pinPillPosition = 0;
          });
        },
        icon: destinationIcon));
    // set the route lines on the map from source to destination
    // for more info follow this tutorial
    setPolylines();
  }

  void setPolylines() async {
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(googleAPIKey,
        PointLatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
      PointLatLng(destinationLocation.latitude,destinationLocation.longitude));

    if(result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      print("not empty");
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });

      setState(() {
        _polylines.add(Polyline(
            width: 3, // set the width of the polylines
            polylineId: PolylineId("poly"),
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 122, 198),
            points: polylineCoordinates));
      });
    }
  }

  void updatePinOnMap() async {
    // create a new CameraPosition instance
    // every time the location changes, so the camera
    // follows the pin as it moves with an animation
    CameraPosition cPosition = CameraPosition(
      zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
      tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
      bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
      target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
    );
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cPosition));
    // do this inside the setState() so Flutter gets notified
    // that a widget update is due
    setState(() {
      // updated position
      var pinPosition =
      LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);

      sourcePinInfo.location = pinPosition;

      // the trick is to remove the marker (by id)
      // and add it again at the updated location
      _markers.removeWhere((m) => m.markerId.value == 'sourcePin');
      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('sourcePin'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              currentlySelectedPin = sourcePinInfo;
              pinPillPosition = 0;
            });
          },
          position: pinPosition, // updated position
          icon: sourceIcon));
    });
  }
}
```

//And the stack that was coming is below

```
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation( 9741): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6584ea0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x90713ec0)
E/BufferQueueProducer( 9741): [SurfaceTexture-0-9741-1] setAsyncMode: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer( 9741): [SurfaceTexture-0-9741-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
Restarted application in 3,158ms.
W/DynamiteModule( 9741): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 9741): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 9741): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 9741): callback not found for CALLBACK_CAP_CHANGED message
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 9741): callback not found for CALLBACK_IP_CHANGED message
W/DynamiteModule( 9741): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 9741): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 9741): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 9741): callback not found for CALLBACK_IP_CHANGED message
I/Google Maps Android API( 9741): Google Play services package version: 203019022
D/        ( 9741): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x872a9500, tid 10180
D/EGL_emulation( 9741): eglCreateContext: 0x8f55fda0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation( 9741): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6584ea0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x90713ec0)
I/flutter ( 9741): GOOGLE MAPS URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.3524217%2C77.3368383&destination=28.354017%2C77.16059159999998&mode=driving&avoidHighways=false&avoidFerries=true&avoidTolls=false&key=API_KEY
D/EGL_emulation( 9741): eglMakeCurrent: 0x8f55fda0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x8f4360f0)

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset:

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:223:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:669:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:652:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:360:22)
#5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:80)
#6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:108:19)
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:334:9)
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:26)
(elided 13 frames from dart:async)

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#b540c(), name: "", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: 

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:223:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:669:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:652:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#b540c(), name: "", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/zygote  ( 9741): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 49007(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(720KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 587us total 174.752ms
I/zygote  ( 9741): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 18774(778KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 42% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 1.075ms total 187.684ms
I/zygote  ( 9741): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 4679(318KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 42% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 22.482ms total 146.268ms
D/        ( 9741): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3bc5200, tid 9963
D/        ( 9741): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3bc5d40, tid 10271
D/        ( 9741): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x77dfe380, tid 10294
```

Comment: Can you also share the emulator and physical device details like their SDK versions, models, etc? Sharing min and target SDKs would also be helpful.

Comment: //for emulator minSdkVersion 21 targetSdkVersion 28 and my physical device is mi A1 with currently android 9 version and also polylines are not visible on both emulator and real device

Comment: I removed your API key from your error logs, please do not share them on public sites

Comment: Is the location permission on your device enabled and can be access by the app?